# Angular 4, a PUT http request returns me an error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method that sends some JSON data and receives JSON data back. I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.json (http.es5.js:797)
    at MapSubscriber.project (api.service.ts:172)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
```

```
this.api.editProduct(this.PID, SCHEMA).subscribe( data => {                        
    this.mediator.openDynamicSnackBar(`Το προϊόν ενημερώθηκε`, 'success', 'ok');                           
    this.router.navigate([`/crm/admin/products`]);

}, error => {
  console.log(error);
  this.mediator.openDynamicSnackBar('Error while updating', 'error','ok');
});
```

`api.service.ts`:

```
 /**
   * Edit the selected product, takes an id and the new object as parameter
   * @param id
   * @param newProduct
   */
  editProduct(id: any, newProduct: any) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const body = JSON.stringify(newProduct);

    return this.http.put(`${this.BASE_URL}/api/products/${id}`, body, { headers: headers })
      .map( res => res.json())
  }
```

Comment: I'd have to guess you're using HttpClient, which automatically parses a json response so you need to delete `.map( res => res.json() )`. If you're not using HttpClient, and using Http instead, you'll want to json stringify your python response.

Comment: Thnx Bro Works i just sent `return jsonify({'message': 'product_updated'}), 200`

Comment: End is worked :)

Comment: Can I ask you if you know very well angular 4 ??

Comment: I'm pretty solid as far as Angular goes